# How to remove cart items on signing out

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, e-commerce, cart

I am removing cartItems from localStorage but still, the cart is showing the selected items.

Redux action for signing out.

```
export const signout = () => (dispatch) => {
      localStorage.removeItem('userInfo'); 
      localStorage.removeItem('cartItems');
      localStorage.removeItem('shippingAddress');  
      dispatch({type: USER_SIGNOUT})
}
```

Fetching Cart Items on Cart Screen.

```
const cart = useSelector(state=> state.cart);
const {cartItems} = cart;
```

Sign In reducer

```
export const userSigninReducer = (state={},action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_SIGNIN_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true};
        case USER_SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
            return {loading: false,userInfo: action.payload};
        case USER_SIGNIN_FAIL:
            return {loading: false,error: action.payload};
        case USER_SIGNOUT:
            return {};
            default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share code for cart reducer?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sun-bz3u7

Comment: updated the answer with code, try that once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at this line

```
const cart = useSelector(state=> state.cart);
```

I suspect that you have a cart reducer and you are getting the data from that reducer and showing it in UI.

While signing out, You are making sure that localstorage is clear and userDetails is flushed out.

```
dispatch({type: USER_SIGNOUT})
```

**SOLUTION**: with this you also need to `dispatch` one more action to cart reducer so that cart details gets reset again.

Add more action `dispatch({type: "CART_RESET"});` so that you can reset the cart reducer,

```
export const signout = () => (dispatch) => {
      localStorage.removeItem('userInfo'); 
      localStorage.removeItem('cartItems');
      localStorage.removeItem('shippingAddress');  
      dispatch({type: USER_SIGNOUT});
      // as you are removing stuffs from localStorage
      // you also need to reset the data from reducer
      dispatch({type: "CART_RESET"});
}
```

so your cart reducer handler should look something like this

```
case "CART_RESET": return { ...state, cartItems: [] }
```

This will make sure you are resetting the CART while siging-out,
also follow the same practice to reset other reducer data if needed while resetting or umounting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving the issue.